# How do I get count of each value from a pandas Data Frame column if the column elements is a set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data set which has a column whose elements are a set like below

```
index  set_column
0    {5520986, 5520236}
1    {5520986, 5520236}
2    {5471829, 5515351}
3    {5471829, 5515351}
4    {5471829, 5515351}
5    {5471829, 5515351}
6    {5471829, 5515351}
7    {5471829, 5515351}
```

what i am trying to get is count of each unique values.

```
 set            count
{5520986, 5520236} 2
{5471829, 5515351} 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df = df["set_column"].value_counts().reset_index()
df.columns = ["set", "count"]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  set  count
0  {5471829, 5515351}      6
1  {5520986, 5520236}      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
df['Count']=df.groupby().cumcount()
df=df.groupby(['set_column'].max()
```